# IFF function in KQL azure analytics?

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-sentinel

I am trying to create an ifelse statement in KQL but I cannot find documentation about if its possible to do what I am trying.
Basically what I am trying to do to summarize ONLY if the conditions(EventResults=="Success") are met and do another summarize if they arent.
summarize SuccessCount=count(), SuccessUsers=makeset(User) by SrcDvcIpAddr, bin(TimeGenerated, timeframe)
ELSE
summarize FailCount=count(), SuccessUsers=makeset(User) by SrcDvcIpAddr, bin(TimeGenerated, timeframe)

I didnt really find any information about where and how I could use iff other than with the extend operator on the offical microsoft documentation page.
Is what I am trying to do possible?

Comment: You already asked this question and was asked to provide sample data + required results in textual format, e.g., CSV.

Comment: Please avoid tag spamming. Tag your query with the actual service you are using and not various services that make usage of KQL.

Comment: Please improve the question so it could server well other SO users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Sample data generation. Not Part of the solution.
let imAuthentication = materialize(range i from 1 to 500 step 1 | extend User = strcat("user_", tostring(toint(rand(10))+1)), SrcDvcIpAddr = tostring(dynamic(["1.1.1.1", "2.2.2.2", "3.3.3.3"])[toint(rand(2))]), EventResult = tostring(dynamic(["Success", "Failure"])[toint(rand(2))]), EventType ="Logon", EventProduct = "AAD", TimeGenerated = ago(12h * rand()));
// Solution starts here.
let sigin_threshold = 5;
let endtime         = 12h;
let timeframe       = 15m;
imAuthentication
|where  TimeGenerated >= ago(endtime) 
    and EventProduct  == "AAD"
    and EventType     =="Logon" 
    and EventResult   in ("Success", "Failure")
    and SrcDvcIpAddr  != "-" 
    and isnotempty(User)
|summarize  SuccessCount = countif(EventResult == "Success")
           ,FailCount    = countif(EventResult == "Failure")
           ,SuccessUsers = make_set_if(User, EventResult == "Success")           
           ,FailUsers    = make_set_if(User, EventResult == "Failure") 
         by SrcDvcIpAddr
           ,bin(TimeGenerated, timeframe)
|where FailCount > sigin_threshold
```

| SrcDvcIpAddr | TimeGenerated | SuccessCount | FailCount | SuccessUsers | FailUsers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2.2.2.2 | 2023-01-20T10:15:00Z | 3 | 7 | ["user_3","user_2"] | ["user_8","user_2","user_10","user_6","user_3","user_5"] |
| 2.2.2.2 | 2023-01-20T11:00:00Z | 4 | 6 | ["user_9","user_3","user_6"] | ["user_8","user_7","user_2","user_4","user_9"] |
| 1.1.1.1 | 2023-01-20T11:15:00Z | 4 | 6 | ["user_10","user_7","user_4"] | ["user_9","user_4","user_3"] |
| 1.1.1.1 | 2023-01-20T11:45:00Z | 3 | 6 | ["user_2","user_1","user_7"] | ["user_2","user_1","user_9","user_4"] |
| 2.2.2.2 | 2023-01-20T12:15:00Z | 3 | 8 | ["user_4","user_5"] | ["user_6","user_8","user_7","user_2","user_3","user_1","user_5"] |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA4WTUW/TMBDH3yv1Oxx5iqG0TVGfpk6qGCAkhCY6nqap8pJrYhHble0Mivrhd3bcNgkD4oc2d7nf/fO/y2wGGy73NULBHYcSFRruhFZT%20Kod3HLjQO/AVQhW103IjEc1OhBy3VBYOZGHAliB5A6N4LX4janhqkQQsDNaQgZOw3I%20B%20twT3dHwF8OVQHfLRoqtM4QJE0aut0mE3qaIkKVqdNCOc8q0mzO2JuMsQlsTH7zlH/er4vCF58fLg6KS5Gn90k2DYdIyWIajv/7bhpO8sDuO9wFYw8E/fBEr/INbVO7l5mbJs/RWg/6yEXdGPwH6O6wR1glX3SpVRJjt0YXTe7pyXp9Q9E7IfFTazgWFOalTrNFBa8h8BhjV%20PRjAYUjSebaBwWKjQYh2BFKdTWVQZtpWsPWV61GXLXER9O1woIHXM%20sTP8nKXcUlJuONLx6PjTN4OB1OtWa2zBYDzyFNLcf1FYxVcd5IM5oe/JoSEhzgFAKEhfcp5dCnrbAK%20o5dsuT1ilHcq9O6R%202ajwaBspuaElBYjo97pRfjC5/xW7tLcMRDwpiG3jNfFq2tJg4t%20qB6JP1RHqVdnw8fzArUW3JYKPDVayq6JD%20VNQywuC/o88S%20uCHg89U/stHoVKe9swuawTOy/MxZnr4Y4%20A1mQ30xyBAAA)